# Sankey chart python

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am trying to make a sankey chart in Python that looks like this:

[image: figure]

but I am having trouble with it as it make loops as you can see:

[image: figure1]

What am I doing wrong?

My script is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
      node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A4", "A2", "A6", "A3", "A5"], 
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                target = [0, 6, 8, 5, 9, 3, 1, 7, 2, 4], 
                value =  [951, 795, 469, 408, 320, 1507 ,327 ,295, 288, 232] 
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

Comment: As you can see from the source and target source: the first source 0 (A1) is not supposed to be targeted anywhere as there is only on A1. The same applies for A6. I don't know if this is the thing that makes the chart look like that?

Answer (score 0):

Plotly connects the 1st value of the source list with the 1st value of the target list, the 2nd value of the source list with the 2nd value of the target list, etc..

That means following lines are drawn:

| from | to |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 (A1) | 0 (A1) | loop |
| 1 (A2) | 6 (A2) |  |
| 2 (A3) | 8 (A3) |  |
| 3 (A4) | 5 (A5) |  |
| 4 (A5) | 9 (A5) |  |
| 0 (A1) | 3 (A3) |  |
| 1 (A2) | 1 (A2) | loop |
| 2 (A3) | 7 (A6) |  |
| 3 (A4) | 2 (A3) |  |
| 4 (A5) | 4 (A5) | loop |

As you can see, lines are drawn from A1 (idx 0) to A1 (idx 0), from A2 (idx 1) to A2 (idx 1) and from A5 (idx 4) to A5 (idx 4).

The green-orange graph from the question cannot be produced with plotly as it does not give the option to have nodes without connection.

Comment: This depends on your desired output... You haven't yet described which nodes should be connected to each other.

Comment: I want the following connected:
A2 (1) to A6 (6)
A3 (2) to  A3 (8)
A4 (3) to A4 (5)
A5 (4) to A5 (9)

Comment: Then use the following lists: `label = ["A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"]` and `source = [0, 1, 2, 3],   target = [4, 5, 6, 7], value =  [951, 795, 469, 408] `